# I can't see my device in Android adb list

Tags: adb, usb-connection-mode, usb-debugging, usb-drivers

I have `LG G3` with `android 5.0 lollipop` and I want to connect it to my laptop with `windows 8.1` OS (For using unity remote).

When I connect my phone I can access to storage but `I can't see my device in adb.exe`. I tried many solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801676/lg-g3-device-not-recognized-by-eclipse) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb) but nothing work for me.

For now in developer mode I checked  these:

- Stay awake
- USB debugging
- Allow mock locations

And I installed the driver from lg website. This is output for `adb usb` command:

```
shell@g3:/ $ adb usb
adb usb
error: device not found
```

Actually I really confused because I think it recognize my device and show `g3` name but I don't know why it can't show my device name in attached device!!!

This is windows command prompt screenshot:
[image: adb]

Without lg driver installed, my device in device manager is like image below and when I try to update the driver using `Android\android-sdk\extras\google\usb_driver` it say: `Windows could not find driver software for your device`

[image: without lg driver]

And when I install lg driver, my device is like image below and again i can't update driver and it say: `Windows has determine the driver software for your device is up to date`

[image: My device with LG driver installed]

Comment: It looks like you already *are* using your device through ADB. The normal Windows command prompt looks like `C:\Users\hossein>`, while yours is `shell@g3:/ $`. That's what a Unix prompt looks like, and that means you're in your device's shell interface. If I am correct about this, then the reason your `adb devices` command doesn't work is because your phone is looking for other *phones* connected to it - of which it finds none.

Comment: @aureljared I didn't  get it, Why my phone need to connect to another phones? And what I need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think I made my point clear. :D Your phone doesn't need to connect to another phone. What I'm saying is that it's possible that you're already successfully using ADB to connect to your phone, because the screenshot you uploaded (`shell@g3`) looks like the shell of your phone. What commands did you enter until you got to that screen?

Comment: Asking the same with different words: what is that "black screenshot" from? From a command-prompt on your Windows machine, or from a terminal shell on your device? The `shell@g3` shows you are executing `adb devices` ***on the G3***, not on your Windows computer. What happens when you execute `adb devices` from the ***Windows*** prompt?

Comment: @Izzy This screenShot is cmd window that run `abd shell`. And that was the result for `adb devices` command

Comment: @aureljared No it's not my phones shell it's windows cmd.

Comment: That's what the other comments were assuming: you try to run `adb devices` ***on the device itself***, which makes no sense – as (usually) there are no other Android devices connected to it. There are some lines missing at the top; I bet one of them reads `adb shell` (which opened a shell to the device, so that's where you are).

Comment: I think it makes no sense to explain it again in different words as you obviously have no knowledge about ADB. Please get yourself a little bit informed about the command you are using: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html. If you read what especially  the command "adb shell" does you should get what was explained above  :)

Answer (score 4):

Go to Settings-->Storage-->Menu(3 dots in the corner) and tap USB computer connection. When there, make sure MTP and PTP are both unchecked.

Comment: Pardon me, but this is impossible to do on some phones that do not support charge-only USB computer mode, such as most Samsung phones post-Gingerbread.

Comment: This does not work on my phone, where I am forced to have at least one of MTP and PTP checked.

Answer (score 2):

I had a hard time getting this to work with my LG G3 on Windows 10. Here's what worked for me:

1. Uninstalled the LG USB Driver.
2. Installed the [Universal ADB Driver](http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver). (Thanks, @[Lucia](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/152437/59789)!)
3. Restarted my computer.
4. Plugged in my phone, went to device manager, and installed it manually as an "Android Composite ADB Interface".
5. Switched the USB connection type on my phone from "MTP" to "PTP".
6. Allowed USB debugging on my phone.

Success!

*Note: Some of these steps may not be necessary, for example, just switching to PTP might work just fine, but I'm documenting what eventually did work for me, and I didn't want to take the time to experiment because if it ain't broke, don't fix it. :)*

[image: ADB finally haz phone!]

Comment: Choosing PTP and enabling USB debugging was enough for me to get it working. (Not sure if PTP was needed, started working after enabling USB debugging)

Comment: The Universal ADB Driver worked for me. Except I didn't need to do steps 3, 4, or 5. However, I did need to perform an additional step: plugging the device into a different USB slot. (Before installing the universal driver I had it in slot 1, but after installation even plugging in and out didn't help; putting it in slot 2 finally made the Windows "new device plugged in" sound, which was followed a few seconds later by the accept-fingerprint popup on my phone, and then successful ADB connection.)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing this problem for two days, and I solved installing the USB driver for my phone LG G3 on my Mac Yosemite. I downloaded the file LGMobileMacDriver_v5.0.zip and installed it and than `adb devices` just worked.

Before anything, just confirm that debug option are enable.

You can try to install the USB driver of your phone, maybe it'll help.
Download Location for Driver [http://www.lg.com/us/support-mobile/lg-LGD850](http://tool.lime.gdms.lge.com/dn/downloader.dev?fileKey=UW00120120425)

Best,

Answer (score 1):

On windows I had to install this software: http://www.koushikdutta.com/post/universal-adb-driver
After the installation android studio started recognizing my phone.