# PC no longer recognizing Android Device

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, usb

While I never had problems before with my Android phone, suddenly one day when I was connecting my phone to the PC via USB it stopped working. Both my PC and my phone didn't detect each other. Strangely enough, it can still charge with the USB cable connected.

I tried the following with no results:

- I supposed the cable was wrong so I bought a brand new one, but still both the PC and the Android phone refused to detect each other.
- Checked in every port of my PC (I tested the functionality of the ports with a normal USB stick, and they work perfectly).
- Enabled USB debugging option in the phone.
- Tried to update USB drivers through Device Manager. The problem here is that it doesn't even show any Android device or at least an unknown device connected to the USB port, so I can't even force the search for new drivers.

[image]

- I also tested both cables with two other Android phones I have (suspecting it was the fault of the phone), but still no results.

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit, and my phone has Android 5.0. I tested with a Samsung, and LG, and a Huawei but neither worked.

Do you have any idea or advice on how to solve this?

Comment: What device are you using?

Comment: LGK200MT (X Style)

Comment: This link may help you. Download driver mentioned in @HEWhoDoesn'tKnow's answer, and follow the steps in this link  https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb?rq=1

Comment: Does the Android phone recognize the USB connection? Have you checked the phone USB port for dust?

Comment: The Android phone doesn't recognize it's been connected to the PC, but it does begin to charge normally (that's why I initially thought it was an issue with the cable). But I checked with a brand new USB cable, and even tried other two phones I found but neither of them worked. I also checked for dust in all the USB ports of my computer, and they work just fine when I insert a memory USB stick.

Comment: Thanks @RahulGopi, I'm going to try that solution this afternoon to see if I can get it to run with the Google drivers.

Comment: @Charlie If you succeeded, you may like to self answer- that would help others in future

Comment: @besshyams To be honest, the problem just randomly dissapeared before I even tried one of the previous methods, so I'm not really sure what happened. At least this discards a problem with the drivers, the USB cable, or the phone itself, and the solution was likely to a hidden update of my PC I'm unaware off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, the problem suddenly faded away before even trying one of the previous solutions. This discards a problem with the USB connection, the phone, or the USB drivers from the PC.

My best guess is that a hidden update or a background program (of which I'm unaware of) was causing the problem, so if anyone has a similar issue, by best advice is to follow the advices of updating the drivers, restoring to a previous state, or just switch ports until finding one that works.

Answer (score 1):

That must be a USB Driver problem. Download the files in [here](https://www.mobileusbdrivers.com/2016/11/lg-x-style-mobile-usb-drivers-download.html) and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded the files, installed them, restarted the computer, and tried again to connect the Android to the PC via USB. However, it still fails to detect the device on both sides. I even checked with the other phones by downloading their drivers and neither of them are recognized even with the brand new USB cable. I'll try later on another computer later to see if the problem is indeed my PC.